# Printing an update line whenever a subprocess finishes in Python 3's multiprocessing Pool

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing

I'm using Python's `multiprocessing` library to process a list of inputs with the built-in `map()` method. Here's the relevant code segment:

```
subp_pool = Pool(self.subprocesses)
cases = subp_pool.map(self.get_case, input_list)
return cases
```

The function to be run in parallel is `self.get_case()`, and the list of inputs is `input_list`.

I wish to print a progress prompt to the standard output in the following format:

```
Working (25/100 cases processed)
```

How can I update a local variable inside the class that contains the Pool, so that whenever a subprocess finishes, the variable is incremented by 1 (and then printed to the standard output)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no way to do this using `multiprocessing.map`, because it doesn't alert the main process about anything until it's completed all its tasks. However, you can get similar behavior by using [`apply_async`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.multiprocessing.Pool.apply_async) in tandem with the `callback` keyword argument:

```
from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool
from functools import partial
import time

class Test(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.count = 0
        self.threads = 4

    def get_case(self, x):
        time.sleep(x)

    def callback(self, total, x):
        self.count += 1
        print("Working ({}/{}) cases processed.".format(self.count, total))

    def do_async(self):
        thread_pool = Pool(self.threads)
        input_list = range(5)
        callback = partial(self.callback, len(input_list))
        tasks = [thread_pool.apply_async(self.get_case, (x,), 
                                         callback=callback) for x in input_list]
        return [task.get() for task in tasks]

if __name__ == "__main__":
    t = Test()
    t.do_async()
```

Comment: Why are you using `multiprocessing.dummy` instead of `multiprocessing`?

Comment: @mittelmania Your code was referencing threads, so I assumed you were using them, too. Feel free to remove the `.dummy` from my example, it should work exactly the same (assuming you're using Python 3.x as stated in the question).

Answer (score 0):

Call the print_data() from the get_case() method and you are done.

```
from threading import Lock

Class A(object):

def __init__(self):
    self.mutex = Lock()
    self.count = 0

def print_data(self):
    self.mutex.acquire()
    try:
        self.count += 1
        print('Working (' + str(self.count) + 'cases processed)')
    finally:
        self.mutex.release()
```

Comment: That that this won't work if you're using a process pool instead of a thread pool.